# Как создать контейнер с горизонтальным скроллом автоматической ширины

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Прошу обратить внимание на категории: вручную, холодно, тепло, жарко. Сейчас для контейнера с фильтрами заданы следующие стили:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
```

У самого фильтра стили такие: `flex: 0 0 auto;`

То есть при большом количестве фильтров появляется горизонтальный скролл, но при уменьшении ширины экрана в определенный момент сам блок с фильтрами перестает сужаться и выпадает. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему и сделать так, чтобы блок с фильтрами постепенно сужался и не выпадал? Именно постепенно. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.cont {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 630px;
  background-color: #fde333;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

input {
  display: none;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

label {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 15px 8px 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="filter popup__filter">
      <input type="checkbox" name="все" value="все" id="все" checked />
      <label class="filter__category popup__category" for="все">Все</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Кухня" value="Кухня" id="Кухня" />
      <label class="filter__category popup__category" for="Кухня">Кухня</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Зал" value="Зал" id="Зал" />
      <label class="filter__category popup__category" for="Зал">Зал</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Лампочки" value="Лампочки" id="Лампочки" />
      <label class="filter__category popup__category" for="Лампочки">Лампочки</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Камеры" value="Камеры" id="Камеры" />
      <label class="filter__category popup__category" for="Камеры">Камеры</label>

      <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" id="1" checked />
      <label class="filter__category favorite-devices__categor" for="1">qwqweq</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" id="2" />
      <label class="filter__category favorite-devices__categor" for="2">1qwseqw</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3" id="3" />
      <label class="filter__category favorite-devices__categor" for="3">qwdqwdas</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="4" value="4" id="4" />
      <label class="filter__category favorite-devices__categor" for="4">sdva</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="5" value="5" id="5" />
      <label class="filter__category favorite-devices__category" for="5">dfs</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: То, что уже сделано.]

Comment: Впрос должен содержать пример, а не скрин

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не знал, что нужен именно пример. Вот упрощенный вариант, который отражает загвоздку.
https://codepen.io/dimkadenisov/pen/YOpXyK

Comment: Добавьте блоку `wrap` свойство `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно задать свойство `min-width` для блока с классом `filter popup__filter`, в сочетании с `max-width` попап не будет вырастать больше заданного размера, а на маленьких девайсах корректно сожмется.